# How do I programmatically check a composer image version is valid before creating a new environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

The following image version is not valid: `composer-2.3.3-airflow-2.5.1`

If you try to create a new environment (`gcloud composer environments create`) with that image it will hang for 40+ minutes and then return errors like these:

```
Waiting for [projects/myproj/locations/us-central1/environments/my-new-env] to be created with [projects/myproj/locations/us-central1/operations/ffde6ed7-8b8a-4dc6-add7-dea16319fd38].....failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.create) Error creating [projects/myproj/locations/us-central1/environments/my-new-env]: Operation [projects/myproj/locations/us-central1/operations/ffde6ed7-8b8a-4dc6-add7-dea16319fd38] failed: CREATE operation failed. Could not trigger cluster creation: Master version must be one of "REGULAR" channel supported versions [1.22.17-gke.14100, 1.23.17-gke.8400, 1.24.14-gke.1400, 1.24.14-gke.2700, 1.25.10-gke.1400, 1.25.10-gke.2700, 1.26.5-gke.1400, 1.26.5-gke.2700, 1.27.2-gke.1200, 1.27.3-gke.100].
```

I wouldn't care if I didn't have to wait 40 minutes for it to fail.

I'm not checking package upgrades here I'm creating a whole new env and seeing these errors if I pick an image version that is too old.

Is there some api call I can make that checks if the image is supported? Even an official endpoint I can hit with a list of supported versions to compare to: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering is indicating that the specified **GKE master version** is not one of the supported versions and must be the **"REGULAR"** channel.

When creating a Google Cloud Composer environment, ensure that you specify a GKE master version that is compatible with the environment. This is typically done in the gcloud composer environments create command with the `--image-version` option.

```
--image-version=composer-2.3.3-airflow-2.5.1
```

Before creating the environment, ensure that the GKE master version you specify is one of the supported versions for the "REGULAR" channel. The GKE master version is different from the Composer image version. The GKE master version represents the version of the Kubernetes control plane that manages your cluster. It's important to choose a GKE master version that is compatible with your environment setup.

Verify the available GKE master versions for the "REGULAR" channel in your Google Cloud project's region (us-central1 in your case). You can find this information in the Google Cloud Console or by using the gcloud command-line tool.

gcloud CLI:

```
gcloud container get-server-config --flatten="channels" --filter="channels.channel=REGULAR" \
    --format="yaml(channels.channel,channels.defaultVersion)" --location="us-central1"
```

Output:
channel: `REGULAR`
defaultVersion: `1.27.3-gke.100`

Comment: Ok, but I can't just specify the GKE master version right? I have a version string that looks like this: `composer-2.3.3-airflow-2.5.1`. How does that at all correspond to GKE version `1.27.3-gke.100`? My question is about programmatically checking if my _composer_ version string is supported. Can I programmatically derive the GKE version from the composer image version? Before actually creating an environment?